# In hive, how to generate dynamic table name in hql?

Tags: hive, hql

i want generate dynamic table name in hql which runing using beeline.

in db2, i can implement this requirement using `||`.
for example, using year to generate table name `'as400.trxfintrx_' || year(current date)`, but how can i implement this in hive'hql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it correct, you want the table name to be paramterized,

For that you can use hive variables,

```
create table dbName.table1_${hivevar:yearMonthDate}
(
c1 int,
c2 int
)
stored as orc
tblproperties('ZLIB');

$ hive -f test_create_table.hql --hivevar yearMonthDate=20190215
OK
Time taken: 1.149 seconds
$ hive
Hive-on-MR is deprecated in Hive 2 and may not be available in the future versions. Consider using a different execution engine (i.e. spark, tez) or using Hive 1.X releases.
hive> use dbname;
OK
Time taken: 0.726 seconds
hive> desc table1_20190215;
OK
c1                      int
c2                      int
Time taken: 0.302 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

you can refer https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+VariableSubstitution

From beeline terminal, you cannot define any function to set parameter value and then use them in you queries.

Hope this helps

Comment: `create table dbName.table1_${hivevar:yearMonthDate}
(
c1 int,
c2 int
)
stored as orc
tblproperties('ZLIB');` this works for beeline cli?

Comment: yes, it will but you should define the variable before you use it...hive> set hivevar:monthDate=2018;
hive> select 1 where ${hivevar:monthDate}=2018;
OK
1
Time taken: 1.868 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)